# jquery ui dialog open multiple dialog boxes using the same class on the button and the content div

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, multiple-instances

i want to open multiple dialog boxes by using the same class on both the button and the content div. The below works but only for the first time.

```
jQuery('.helpDialog').hide();

jQuery('.helpButton').click(function() {  
    jQuery(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog({  
    autoOpen: true,  
    title: 'Help',  
    width: 500,  
    height: 300,  
    position: [180,10],  
    draggable: true,    
    resizable: false,  
    modal: false  
    });  
return false;  
});
```

we know the reason for this 
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/
"the second call is ignored because the dialog has already been instantiated on that element."

But when i fix that problem by trying the code below, the dialog box no longer opens.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

```
jQuery('.helpDialog').hide();

jQuery(function() {  
    jQuery('.helpDialog').dialog({  
        autoOpen: false,  
        modal: true,  
        title: 'Info',  
        width: 600,  
        height: 400,  
        position: [200,0],  
        draggable: false  
    });  
});  

jQuery('.helpButton').click(function() {  
    jQuery(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog('open');  
    return false;  
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You actually need a different approach here, a non-intuitive one, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.helpButton').each(function() {  
    $.data(this, 'dialog', 
      $(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
        modal: true,  
        title: 'Info',  
        width: 600,  
        height: 400,  
        position: [200,0],  
        draggable: false  
      })
    );  
  }).click(function() {  
      $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');  
      return false;  
  });  
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZwLcE/).

*Why must you do this?* because [`.dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) moves the content it wraps in dialog elements to the end of the `<body>`, so [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will no longer find it...by using [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) we're maintaining a reference to the dialog we want to open.

Comment: Wow that was so quick, Ive got it up and running thanks Nick.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code will help you.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#opener1").click(function () {
            $("<div id='dialog1' />").dialog(
            {
                title: 'Basic modal dialog1',
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                }
            });

            $("#dialog1").dialog('open').show();
            return false;
        });


        $("#opener2").click(function () {
            $("<div id='dialog2' />").dialog(
            {
                title: 'Basic modal dialog2',
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                }
            });

            $("#dialog2").dialog('open').show();
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button id="opener1">open the dialog1</button>
    <button id="opener2">open the dialog2</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.helpButton').each(function() {  
$.data(this, 'dialog', 
$(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog({
autoOpen: false,  
modal: true,  
title: 'Info',  
width: 600,  
height: 400,  
position: [200,0],  
draggable: false  
})
);  
}).click(function() {  
$.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');  
return false;  
});  
});
```