# selecting the right element using jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-dialog

Starting from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518917/86112) provided by the Nick Caver I wish to save some inputs provided by the users into a db. The problem is that I don't know how to select the right input from the current dialog box, using jQuery.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddole/AC5mP/4/) is my working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve it. I had to use :last selector. I think is a good solution.

What do you think? I'm new in jQuery